# display all data in a table from sql in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm just learning asp.net with c#. with the little knowledge of php, i think i'm able to do somethings but i'm having problem displaying records from my database.

i have a table called resources, what i want to do is output all the data in the table.
this is the output i want to write in c# in php...

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($tablename))
{
   echo "<tr><td>$row->image</td><td><a href='#'>download link</a></td><a href='http://'".$row->url."'>'".$row->url."'</a></tr>";
}
?>
```

basically i don't have problem with the php but i want the output this code will give me same in C#(with image, download link, and url in a table). Please help,...

i have this code in c# to output data in a label control

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM resources");
Knct dal = new Knct();
MySqlDataReader dr = dal.DatareaderMethod(cmd, Knct.executemethods.ExecuteReader);
while (dr.Read())
{
  label1.Text = dr[2].ToString();
}
```

the while loop is not working, it only display one value. how do i make this a display all records in the database and which asp control can i use to output the records and also make a url link in the table output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPivot" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySql %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MySql.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM resources"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is the simplest way to bind data to a gridview or any other data control.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.Net, a repeater is preferred for simple displays.

In your code behind (or server-side), you'll have to bind the data to the repeater:

```
   ...
   m_Repeater.DataSource = GetImages();  //Function that returns Image records
   m_Repeater.DataBind();
   ...
```

The mark up on your ASPX page will look something like:

```
<asp:Repeater id="m_Repeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Link</td>
        <td>Url</td>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td><img src='<%# Container.DataItem("ImageSrc") %>'/></td>
        <td><a href='<%# Container.DataItem("DownloandLink") %>'>Download Link</a></td>
        <td><a href='<%# Container.DataItem("ImageUrl") %>'>Url</a></td>
      </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
     </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**ASP.Net MVC**

If you're using ASP.Net MVC you can use the Razor syntax, it's more elegant. Assuming `Model` is strongly-typed to an enumerable list of `Image` objects, the markup on your view page might look something like:

```
@foreach(var image in Model)
{
   <tr>
     <td><img src='@image.ImageSrc'/></td>
     <td><a href='@image.DownloadLink'>Download Link</a></td>
     <td><a href='@image.ImageUrl'>Url</a></td>
   </tr>
}
```

Some useful Articles/Resources:

- [MSDN - Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [DotNetcurry - Razor](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=601)

Comment: following the MSDN link your gave gave me an insight about what i should use.."Repeater", it shows that i can output my queries directly on the asp page. i searched for how to use repeater then got this website which explains better.
[c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/databinding-with-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp/)

thanks for your response, it really help...

Comment: That's great. If you're just starting out, I would also suggest checking out ASP.Net MVC solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If this is webforms, you can use a repeater to display each of your values.  It'd look something like this:

```
aspx:
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%# Eval("columnName")%></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

aspx.cs:
repeater.DataSource = dr;
repeater.DataBind();
```

Think of it as a `for` loop.