# What datatype and web control to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET UI WebControls and C# datatypes and I'm not sure what to use for my problem here.

I think I can use the SqlDataReader object type to get some data and the results at most will be anywhere from 5 to 10 rows, so it isn't going to be a huge data set. I want to take that and iterate through the rows to set some dynamic data (build hyperlinks). I'm not sure if I SHOULD use SqlDataReader because the dataset I will end up would be this:

```
 id         name              type
--------------------------------------
 1          John Smith        Person
 2          John's Event      Event
 3          Johnny Fields     Group
```

Then I want to end up with the following code in my .ascx file.

```
<a href="~/default.aspx?page=3&person=1" class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-left">John Smith</span>
    <span class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Person</span>    // here I need to evaluate the type and add a font-awesome icon based on it
</a>
<a href="~/default.aspx?page=14&event=2" class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-left">John's Event</span>
    <span class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Event</span>
</a>
<a href="~/default.aspx?page=2&group=3" class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-left">Johnny Fields</span>
    <span class="float-right"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Group</span>
</a>
```

I'm not sure what WebControl I can use to build this. I'm looking into HyperLinkColumn with DataGrid, but I can't make heads or tails of it. I need help.

Comment: FYI, since you're new to WebForms, WebForms is an antiquated technology.  If you're open to the change, you should consider switching to Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: @Amy I am, unfortunately I am having to do it this way for now on the app I'm working with. It's a side project I'm building to get my feet wet with ASP. I actually am more familiar with ASP MVC.

Comment: Very good then.  Well its been a while, but I think the control you should look at is `GridView`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927746/47589).

Comment: You're really mixing up your concerns if you're talking about how to access the data and how to display the data in the same breath. These should be independent of each other. You should have a data layer to retrieve your data, this should return objects that represent the information. Then you should call into that data layer from your site to get what you need, and bind it to the control of your choice for displaying the data. Don't put your data logic directly in your site logic. That means your website shouldn't have anything from System.Data (including SqlDataReader) in code behind files.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to look at what you want to do. If you want headers, columns, sorting, etc then a Grid is what you need. If you just need a list of stuff, use a Repeater. SqlDataReader is fine. It will give back a forward-only recordset and you can bind the repeater to it. From there just create an ItemTemplate with your databinders inside. You probably don't need any fancy hyperlink controls. Microsoft has a nice simple example of this binding at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396